# Magento: How to get visitor's cookies or session Id on front end

Tags: magento, session, logging, cookies

I want to log the recently viewed product for every visitor on the site. And for that the best way I believe is to log it via their cookie/session ID. How can I get the Session ID/Cookies of a visitor who is not logged in.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get the visitor id by `session`

```
$vistitorId = Mage::getModel('core/session')->getVisitorId();
```

Answer (score 0):

To get Cookies

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getCookie();
```

To get Session Id

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
echo $session->getId();
echo $session->getCustomerId();
```

FYI : There is a default magento functionality available for the recently viewed products

Please check the below url

[Magento: Show Visitor's Recently Viewed Product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33493060/magento-show-visitors-recently-viewed-product)