# Magento: Show Visitor's Recently Viewed Product

Tags: magento, logging, cookies, session-cookies

This question is somehow related to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33492249/magento-how-to-get-visitors-cookies-or-session-id-on-front-end). I want the "recently viewed" section to show the products which are recently viewed by my (as a visitor). So in that way, every visitor will see their recently viewed products in that section. 
**Does magento provide any default functionality for this feature** or do I have to do it the way I referred in my previous question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes magento has its default functionality
Goto `app/design/frontend/default/(yourtheme)/tempalte/reports` folder

If you cant see that folder in your theme, just copy it and save it to your theme folder

you can use the below code to display in layout files

```
<block type="reports/product_viewed" name="left.reports.product.viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml" />
```

To call in CMS pages (homepage)

```
{{block type="reports/product_viewed" name="left.reports.product.viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml"}}
```

To call in phtml file

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('reports/product_viewed')->setTemplate('reports/product_viewed.phtml')->tohtml(); ?>
```

Comment: Saved me an hour
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
yes , you can by simply use this 
<cms_index_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="reports/product_viewed" name="home.reports.product.viewed" alias="product_viewed" template="reports/home_product_viewed.phtml" after="product_new">   
            <action method="addPriceBlockType">
                <type>bundle</type>
                <block>bundle/catalog_product_price</block> 
                <template>bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</cms_index_index>
```